# Wercker Firebase Deployment issue

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration, firebase-authentication, wercker

I am trying automate Deployment to Firebase Hosting via Wercker and I am continously getting this error.

Following this tutorial

https://medium.com/@pradeep1991singh/integrate-wercker-with-bitbucket-firebase-and-slack-7eb3bc38543d

### Stack Trace

```
> export WERCKER_STEP_ROOT="/pipeline/script-5ea4a2c6-b11f-4972-991a-eec61b3d43af"
export WERCKER_STEP_ID="script-5ea4a2c6-b11f-4972-991a-eec61b3d43af"
export WERCKER_STEP_OWNER="wercker"
export WERCKER_STEP_NAME="script"
export WERCKER_REPORT_NUMBERS_FILE="/report/script-5ea4a2c6-b11f-4972-991a-eec61b3d43af/numbers.ini"
export WERCKER_REPORT_MESSAGE_FILE="/report/script-5ea4a2c6-b11f-4972-991a-eec61b3d43af/message.txt"
export WERCKER_REPORT_ARTIFACTS_DIR="/report/script-5ea4a2c6-b11f-4972-991a-eec61b3d43af/artifacts"
source "/pipeline/script-5ea4a2c6-b11f-4972-991a-eec61b3d43af/run.sh" < /dev/null
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.071Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.076Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase deploy --project --token --debug
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.076Z] CLI Version:   3.9.2
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.076Z] Platform:      linux
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.076Z] Node Version:  v7.10.1
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.077Z] Time:          Tue Aug 15 2017 13:38:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.077Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.091Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.091Z] > no authorization credentials were supplied or found

⚠  Your CLI authentication needs to be updated to take advantage of new features.
⚠  Please run firebase login --reauth
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.093Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"]
[2017-08-15T13:38:45.093Z] > no authorization credentials were supplied or found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was related to the Wercker.yml file. The Step was not defined properly and it seems the environment variable wasnt getting read properly.

Steps to narrow down the issue

1. Log out of Fire base on local and then try to perform a firebase list - should get an error
2. try same with --token passing token and will get a list of all the valid projects if token is valid.
3. Take the valid Project name and token and then hardcode it in yml and try once to make sure the build executes properly
4. Finally when all are working , expose as protected variables and everything works like a charm!!.